# Why Local Classes don't show up in SE38 Classes list?

Tags: abap

I'm writing an ABAP program using OO objects.  In SE38, under the class folder of my program, some of my local classes do not show up. Some do.

All my classes are stored in an 'include'.  As far as I know there's no Class-Builder capability for local classes.

When I rename a class, sometimes it gets renamed in the folder listing mentioned above, sometimes it doesn't.

When I add new classes, sometimes they show up, sometimes they don't.

What am I missing? Is there a particular way to add local classes to an include with other classes and have it show up in the Classes folder?  Is there a way to refresh the listings?

Syntax is is being checked, the program finds the classes, so SAP is reading everything and recognizing it just fine.  It just doesn't display under the classes folder.

As much as I enjoy OO, I'm starting to get the feeling that although it's the path forward, it's also semi-masochistic.  I'm trying to be the leader of our group to encourage OO over classic ABAP.  Things like this though, I have to iron out and understand before I could ever convince others.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of local objects in SE80/SE38 (classes as well as data types, forms and other stuff) isn't refreshed as frequently as one would like. It's not like the Outline view that you might know from Eclipse or similar tools from other IDEs. When in doubt, you might want to right-click the program in the tree view and rebuild the object list. Or you might want to switch to global classes altogether, which gives you a much better tool support.

Comment: I may well switch to global classes.  In this case, it really fits as a program-specific class I was trying to create.  You're also right about the Outline view in Eclipse--that's my experience.  So, many times I'm trying to find the equivalent features in the SAP editor.  But, it's good to know even, that some features are not there in ABAP.  I like to ask, and then know--rather than wonder and forever frustratingly hunt.

Comment: Rebuild Object List did it... Thanks a million, @vwegert.  I feel much better now. There's always an answer! Thank you.    I enjoy learning ABAP, I'm a Java developer tasked with interfacing with SAP with ABAP and external RFC's.  I'm the only one in our shop who gets to work in both worlds.  It's a tremendous opportunity, and I am grateful for it and enjoy it,honestly-- despite my masochistic comment made earlier. It's my goal here to lure/encourage/train others to advance into OO.  Sometimes when people hear OO, they think Uh O!  I want to change that.

Comment: Davidson, I fully understand. I get the shakes every time someone tries to argue that you should only use classes if you absolutely need them and stick to function modules if you can...

Comment: @Davidson in SE24 there's a tool to transform local classes within programs and includes to global classes. It's under the menu. You don't need to copy and paste everything if you need to switch to global classes.